# Coordinate system transformation based on user-inputted points

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two coordinate systems, $S$ and $S'$. Consider the points $P_1$ and $P_2$, with coordinates (-9, -6) and (2, -7) in $S$, respectively. Consider the points $P'_1$ and $P'_2$, with coordinates (450, 390) and (505, 335) respectively, which correspond to the coordinates of $P_1$ and $P_2$ in the coordinate system $S'$.

- Is it possible, based solely on this information, to determine the transformation matrix $S->S'$, so that given any point $P$ = (x, y) we can determine $P'$ = (x', y')?

  - If not, would it be possible by adding more pairs of reference points?

To give a concrete example of what I'm trying to achieve, I have the following image:
[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjQCN.jpg). The user inserts some points in the map and their coordinates in $S1$. $S2$ represents the coordinate system of the "application" itself - starting at the bottom left corner (0, 0), having X in the vertical axis going up and Y in the horizontal axis going right, in a "standard grid" -, and $S1$ represents the coordinate system of the actual map in the image - has some unknown degree of rotation, translation and scaling compared to $S1$. I want to, given coordinates in $S1$, be able to place them on the image using $S2$'s coordinates.